# Mapped two arrays... now... can i map three?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dictionary

This mapping worked:

```
@fbc = FbComments.where("reviewee_id = ?", current_user.id)
@users = User.order("last_name")
@fb_comments = @fbc.map! { |fb| [fb, @users.find_by_id(fb.user_id)] }
```

So two arrays are mapped... one with comments and one with the user data of the person that made the comments. But I also need the user's profile picture data. Do i change the original mapping method to include a third array somehow (e.g. @fbc + @users + @pictures), or do i have to map another array on the result of mapping the first two (e.g. @fb_comments + @pictures)?

Profile pictures, like comments, have a user_id that is matched to the id of the user who made the comments.

Thanks.

Comment: @DougR, you interested in taking a crack at this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing this the way you are. Why not use a join (`.includes`) to get everything in one query?

```
@fbc = FbComments.where("reviewee_id = ?", current_user.id).includes(:user => :picture)

@fbc.first.user         # => The first user in the results
@fbc.first.user.picture # => The first user's picture
```

(I'm assuming here that profile picture data is its own model called `Picture`. Change it to fit your app if necessary.)

Take a look at [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) and scroll down to "Eager loading of associations."

Comment: Hey, @Jordan, you were absolutely right. I'm somewhat of a rails 3 noob so the answer and the reference helped me tremendously. Thanks.